# After wrapping my mapped content with a layout component, [object AsyncGenerator] is returned to the page

Tags: javascript, astrojs

When I abstract out the title code to a new layout component, the page stops outputting the objects and instead outputs an AsyncGenerator object.

Here is what the broken code looks like where  just contains a section tag with some styles and the title.

```js
const categories = [chips, kebab];
---

<SectionLayout title="menu">
  <div
    class="m-auto grid w-9/12 grid-flow-row grid-cols-1 gap-x-40 md:grid-cols-2 lg:w-7/12"
  >
    {
      categories.map((category, index) =>
        category.map(function (item) {
          if (item.name == "title") {
            if (index >= 1) {
              return (
                <h3 class="col-span-1 mt-8 border-t-2 border-orange-600 pt-8 pb-4 text-center text-4xl font-semibold uppercase text-zinc-800 md:col-span-2">
                  {item.description}
                </h3>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <h3 class="col-span-1 mt-8 text-center text-4xl font-semibold uppercase text-zinc-800 md:col-span-2">
                  {item.description}
                </h3>
              );
            }
```

This is the before and after applying the section layout block.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like your not resolving a promise correctly. but it's hard to help with the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `.map()` is not formatted correctly, the JSX needs to be wrapped in an empty fragment `<></>`, something like this:

```
{ categories.map((category, index) => <>
    { category.map((item) => {
        ...
    })}
</>)}
```